# Undefined index when trying to remove an item from my cart

Tags: php

I've created an add and remove option for my cart. They work, however, I keep getting undefined index errors when it's first loaded. Is there anything wrong, for example, with the remove option in the cart? This is the code:

```
    $sessionelements = 'cart_' . $_GET['remove'];
    $_SESSION[$sessionelements] = isset($_SESSION[$sessionelements]) ? $_SESSION[$sessionelements] - 1 : 1;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the existence of the $_GET['remove'] variable before doing anything.

```
if (isset($_GET['remove'])) {
    $sessionelements = 'cart_' . $_GET['remove'];
    $_SESSION[$sessionelements] = isset($_SESSION[$sessionelements]) ? $_SESSION[$sessionelements] - 1 : 1;
}
```